# tinyxml parsing xml file

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I have a xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<ApplicationSettings>
    <BeamGeometry  
        Dimension="2"
        Type="fan"
        Shape="arc"
        LengthFocalPointToISOCenter="558"
        LengthISOCenterToDetector="394"
        LengthDetectorSeperation="0.98"
        LengthModuleSeperation="0.04"
        NumberModules="57" 
        NumberDetectorsPerModule="16" 
        NumberISOCenterShift="3.25" />
</ApplicationSettings>
```

And I'd like to use tinyxml retrieving all the values (such as 558) based on the entry name such as (LengthFocalPointToISOCenter). Here is my code, not successful yet.

```
int SetFanbeamGeometry(const char* filename)    
{   
    int ret = TRUE;

    TiXmlDocument doc("E:\\Projects\\iterativeRecon\\ProjectPackage\\ApplicationSettings\\ApplicationSettings.xml");

    int LengthFocalPointToISOCenter;

    if( doc.LoadFile())
    {

        TiXmlHandle hDoc(&doc);
        TiXmlElement *pRoot, *pParm;
        pRoot = doc.FirstChildElement("ApplicationSettings");
        if(pRoot)
        {
            pParm = pRoot->FirstChildElement("BeamGeometry");
            int i = 0; // for sorting the entries
            while(pParm)
            {
                pParm = pParm->NextSiblingElement("BeamGeometry");
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Warning: ApplicationSettings is not loaded!");
        ret = FALSE;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I am wondering how can I use tinyxml to do that? Sorry I am a first time user. and it looks confusing to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one `BeamGeometry` child element in the snippet you've shown; the information you're trying to access are its *attributes* - they're not individual elements.

So you need something like this:

```
// ...
pParm = pRoot->FirstChildElement("BeamGeometry");
if (pParm)
{
    const char* pAttr = pParm->Attribute("LengthFocalPointToISOCenter");
    if (pAttr)
    {
        int iLengthFocalPointToISOCenter = strtoul(pAttr, NULL, 10);
        // do something with the value
    }
}
```

If you want to loop through all attributes, it's quite simple:

```
const TiXmlAttribute* pAttr = pParm->FirstAttribute();
while (pAttr)
{
    const char* name = pAttr->Name(); // attribute name
    const char* value = pAttr->Value(); // attribute value
    // do something
    pAttr = pAttr->Next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I want to loop through all entries?

Comment: @Ono: Added that to the answer.